# Database index not being used causing slow query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes

I have the following two tables:

```
StudentCourse
- Id, 
- StudentId, 
- CourseId
```

Unique index on `StudentId` and `CourseId`

```
StudentCourseCount
- Id, 
- Student1Id, 
- Student2Id, 
- CourseCount
```

Index on `Student1Id` and `CourseCount`

Index on `Student2Id` and `CourseCount`

When I have a `CourseId` I list the students taking the course.  The key that I want to accomplish is under a student I want to list other students that they have previously taking courses with.

I'm trying the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentCourseCount sc
INNER JOIN StudentCourse s1 ON s1.course_id = <id> AND sc.student1_id = s1.student_id
INNER JOIN StudentCourse s2 ON s2.course_id = <id> AND sc.student2_id = s2.student_id
WHERE sc.course_count > 1
```

The query works as expected; however, it is super slow on my extremely large tables (10,000,000+ rows).

When I explain the query, `StudentCourseCount` doesn't use an index.  It properly identifies that there are possible indexes for `Student1Id` and `Student2Id`, but doesn't use either.

> Execution plan: Table: sc Possible keys: Student1Id, Student2Id Key:
>   null Rows: 28648392
>
> Table: c2 Key: student_id Rows: 1
>
> Table: c1 Key: student_id Rows: 1

The first table is clearly scanning and not using a key to filter down quickly.

Comment: can you please copy the execution plan and the index definitions for your tables?

Comment: I'm just curious . . . What application has 10,000,000 rows in a `StudentCourse` table?

Comment: I've added the indexes and described the query execution plan (it didn't copy/paste nicely so I re-wrote the important pieces).

Comment: Pro tip: avoid `SELECT *` in software, especially in queries that access large tables. The need to return all columns can make it hard for the optimizer to satisfy your query cleverly. If you rewrote your query to enumerate the columns you need, you'd help us recommend useful indexing strategies.

Comment: If it is doing a Table scan on StudentCourseCount i guess the `WHERE sc.course_count > 1` is not selective enough

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've worked in a very huge system that manage students and courses and teachers and lessons grade, etc. For schools of an entire state (big state in Brazil). So, this state has about 460 cities and most of the cities has more than 3 or 4 schools (for the small cities, there are some big that has more than 100 schools). Of course that the table wasn't just student/course there are others keys like semester, year, school, etc. But it was HUGE and that data goes back 1999 on that table. Just to clarify how it is possible.

Comment: @OllieJones At the end I will be select the Student1Id and Student2Id so that I can join into the Student table that contains their names.

Comment: @MartinK. it's weird that it doesn't use the sc.student1_id though in the join is it not?

Comment: @endyourif: does "Index on Student1Id and CourseCount" mean a combined index on both columns, or two indexes, one per column?

Comment: @TheChaos a combined index.

Comment: @endyourif: This means it does a table scan on StudentCourseCount and uses the student_id key in the StudentCourse table to find matching rows.

Comment: @MartinK. yep and I'm not sure how to prevent that scan.

Comment: could you try adding an index only on the courseCount column?

Comment: Presumably your query is actually getting students that have shared _more_ than one course.  Do you need the course information?  Note that the query only needs the `StudentCourse` table (although the cross-ref table may make some queries faster).  You need to give us your full query, and what you want the results to actually look like, along with starting sample data.

Comment: I think you can't. If more than 20% or 25% of the rows in StudentCourseCount fulfill course_count > 1 it is probably better to do a table scan. With index, you have to read several index pages (depending on index tree's depth) and a data page. You will have more reads in the end when the condition is not selective. How many rows do you have in each table?

Comment: @MartinK. removing the condition of course count > 1 has no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should put the course_id filter in the outer select also. The only filter you have on StudentCourseCount sc is course_count. Assuming you are only search on 1 course_id, you should have sc.course_count>1 AND sc.course_id = id. Otherwise it's your joins that are trying to apply the filter to the sc.course_count>1 result set.

Assuming there is an even distribution of values, this query (or a variation) should be performant. 10M rows is not extremely large, it's large enough that queries need to be optimized.

Comment: sc doesn't have the course id, it contains the students and their counts.  the course id is filtered in the s1 and s2 tables.

Comment: Ah, then it seems like you want to select from the StudentCourse table first, not StudentCourseCount.

Answer (score 0):

I think Brent Baisley had a good point, i didn't see the `<id>` in the beginning. I guess you want to have both Students in the same course so you can link them in the Join and get the `course_id=<id>` condition in the where clause. I think the optimizer should do such things by itself but it is worth a try:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentCourseCount sc
INNER JOIN StudentCourse s1 ON sc.student1_id = s1.student_id
INNER JOIN StudentCourse s2 ON s2.course_id = s1.course_id AND sc.student2_id = s2.student_id
WHERE sc.course_count > 1 AND s1.course_id = <id>
```

Comment: Moving s1.course_id into the where clause makes it even slower. So this didn't seem to help.

Comment: Ok then again the question how many records do you have in StudentCourseCount and in StudentCourse? How many of the StudentCourseCount records qualify for course_count>1 and how many of the StudentCourse records qualify for course_id=<id>

Comment: It's a 3 to 1 scenario.  The count contains 3 times more than the course.  For each course id it probably matches 50-100 students.  These in turn match about times in the count table returning for a course with 50 students it would return upwords to 500 combinations of each student taking a class with another student.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the tables and resultset sizes? If the StudentCourse table is considerably smaller i wonder why it is not used for the scan.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very large query that is returning a very large result set.  I'm not sure you can optimize it, because of the volume of data being returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM StudentCourseCount sc INNER JOIN
     StudentCourse s1
     ON s1.course_id = <id> AND sc.student1_id = s1.student_id INNER JOIN
     StudentCourse s2
     ON s2.course_id = <id> AND sc.student2_id = s2.student_id
WHERE sc.course_count > 1;
```

The indexes that you want on the tables are `StudentCourseCount(course_count, student_id)` and `StudentCourse(student_id, course_id)`.

Now, you are saying that this query works, by which I assume you mean that you like the results.  It is answering the following question:

> Get all pairs of students who have taken course `id` and have also taken more than one course

This is very different from:

> under a student I want to list other students that they have previously taking courses with.

If this is your real question, I would suggest that you ask another question here on Stack Overflow to get a better query for it.